Where does cryptomount in Grub create decrypted disks
The documentation contains:

Successfully decrypted disks are named as (cryptoX) and have increasing numeration suffix for each new decrypted disk. If the encrypted disk hosts some higher level of abstraction (like LVM2 or MDRAID) it will be created under a separate device namespace in addition to the cryptodisk namespace.

Documentation
My grub.cfg contains the command cryptomount -a. When I boot, I get a passphrase request and a message that the corresponding slot was successfully opened, but the partition can't be found and the system doesn't start. I've opened the Grub command line and manually called cryptomount -a. The command was successful but I can't find any new devices under /dev. The encrypted partition contains an LVM PV and I can't neither see the decrypted device nor the LVs. Where can I find the decrypted disks?
When I decrypt the encrypted device in initramfs with cryptsetup, everything works as expected and I can start the system.

Like the documentation says, GRUB will know the first decrypted disk as (crypto0) if it is a regular partition. If it is some other abstraction, e.g. a LVM PV, then any detected LVs should appear as (lvm/<vgname>-<lvname>), although the documentation for this is currently extremely hard to find: I had to read the source code to find it.
Linux software RAID devices will apparently be known in GRUB by names like (md/<RAID array name or number>), and can also be referenced by (mduuid/<long hex number>).
To list all detected disks/partitions/LVs in GRUB prompt, type ls ( and press Tab.
Any device paths starting with /dev/ are meaningless for GRUB at boot time, as the kernel that would implement the device nodes in /dev/ is not running yet. They might be meaningful as kernel boot parameters, but for GRUB itself, they are just strings with no special meaning.
